# Timer.invalidate() does not work in swift when called from gameviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, timer, viewcontroller, invalidation

I am having trouble with invalidating a timer in my code.
I have declared it like this:

```
var gameTimer: Timer!
```

in the GameView, and used it as so in the viewDidLoad():

```
gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(doAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I have another function in GameView that invalidates the Timer, it looks like this:

```
func pause(){
          if gameTimer != nil {
              gameTimer.invalidate()
              gameTimer = nil
          } 
    }
```

The function above works just as fine as I have tested it in the GameView. However, when I call it in the GameViewController like this:

```
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        if let scene = GameScene(size: view.frame.size) as? GameScene {
            scene.pause()
        }
```

the view switches, which is what I want, but the times does not stop, as I would want.
Does anyone know why?

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    var pauseButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pauseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToMenu), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(pauseButton)


        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }

    }


    func goToMenu(){
        self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        if let scene = GameScene(size: view.frame.size) as? GameScene {
            scene.pause()
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `GameScene` and the calling `pause` in that. You need to call `pause` on the instance that you already have.

Comment: oh, right i didn't think of that. thanks. Hmm... so then do you know how I am supposed to call this GameScene function in GameViewController? I looked everywhere, and that's the only way I found, otherwise it does not work. What I am essentially trying to do is pause the GameScene as I change to a SecondViewController, and the only thing running now is the timer. thanks

Comment: When you create the first game scene instance, you need to,keep a reference to it in a property variable

Comment: how would you do that, because wherever I declare GameScene in GameViewController, I am not able to then say GameScene.pause(). I know there's another way to write GameScene.isPaused = true, but that still does not work

Comment: Where do you create the game scene in the view controller?  Show that code

Comment: I can't figure out how to paste the code in the comment section. However, yes, I am trying to have a button in GameViewController,  that switches views and in the same time pauses the GameScene. Now, the only thing running in GameView is the timer. I stop that through a function. But I cannot call that function in the GameViewController without using it on the same instance of GameScene.

Comment: Don't paste code into the comment. Edit your question to include it there.

Comment: a, ok, got it. I just edited the question. Then in my GameScene i have the following: func pause(){
        if gameTimer != nil {
            gameTimer.invalidate()
            gameTimer = nil
        }
    }